# Logarithm calculator

Tags: c, logging, logarithm

I'm trying to make a logarithm calculator and got stuck—it doesn't print out a value. The problem may be at lines 15 or 24 or both. How can I make it print the value (all written in C).

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Finds base 10 logarithms

int main()
{
    float result;
    float base = 10.0;
    float multiplier = 1.0;
    // float counter1 = 0.0;
    // float counter2 = 0;

    printf("Input result: ");
    scanf("%l", result);

    // Solves for all results above the base
    if(result > base) {
        while(result > multiplier) {
            multiplier =  multiplier * multiplier; // the multiplier has to check non-whole numbers
            multiplier += 0.001;
        } // division
    }
    printf("Your exponent is: %l \n", &multiplier);
    printf("Hello mathematics!");
    return 0;
}
```

All help appreciated,
Xebiq

Comment: scanf("%l", result); should be     scanf("%l", &result); and %l is new to me: do you want %f to scan a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should delete `&` in `printf`,and add `&` in `scanf`.

```
printf("Your exponent is: %f \n", multiplier);
scanf("%f", &result);
```

and use `%f` in them.

and with base `10` I suggest this function to calculate log:

```
unsigned int Log2n(unsigned int n)
{
    return (n > 1) ? 1 + Log2n(n / 10) : 0;
}
```

also you should know about Floating-point numbers here:
`multiplier += 0.001;`

probably exactly `0.001` won't be added to `multiplier` when I debugged this `0.00100005` was being add to `multiplier` in my compiler.(which will affect multiplying)

Comment: There are other issues as well

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked: now I know what to watch out for too.

Answer (score 0):

In printf remove '&' and in scanf add '&' before variable.